# Why am I getting the Notable Question Badge when the question says "3k" views?

Tags: support, badges, views, view-badges

I am getting the notable question badge when it is 3k views, not 2.5k views, but the badge says for 2.5k views. Now awhile ago it wasn't as easy to get this badge but now it is easier. We should not be giving this badge this easily. I am wondering why I didn't get this badge when I had 2.5k views like it said earlier... Seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: It would help if you'd link to the question you're talking about.

Answer (score 8):

Part of the problem seems to be round-off error.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674911/light-weight-er-diagram-tool) had just over 2500 views when I looked at it, but that figure is shortened to 3k in your profile stats.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674911/light-weight-er-diagram-tool), then it's possible that it should have been given just after 2,500, but the service could have been backlogged or not running.

Answer (score -1):

The average question does not receive anywhere near 1,000 views, nevermind 2,500.  So it is a notable question once it's reached that number of views.

Stats:

Older October 2009 data on Stackql (stateoverflow is giving me a 403):

select avg(p.ViewCount) from Posts p

81

I should be removing deleted posts, but I suspect that isn't going to change the average that much.  81 views is not a lot, and 2,500 views is 30 times more than the average.

Comment: Indeed, my most "notable" question only has 328 views. These are badges I will never see.

Comment: What about the average year-old question? I have Notable Question x3; one of those questions got no votes and was closed (by me) within 40 minutes of posting.

Comment: @mmyers - A year ago SO was still just getting settled down, and the data dump in stackql is 4 months older than that.  A year prior to the data in StackQL, SO was *very* new. I don't know that we can trust the outcome of that...

Comment: @mmyers - However, here's the query and results: `select avg(p.ViewCount) from Posts p where p.CreationDate < CAST('2008-10-01' AS datetime)` gives the average viewcount for posts prior to October 2009 as 154.

Comment: The most common view count is 59. `SELECT Posts.ViewCount, COUNT(*) AS posts from Posts GROUP BY Posts.ViewCount ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;`

Comment: Badges based on thousands of views or votes really encourage fluff and "must have" or "strangest type" or "everybody and their hamster" posts. @aet